# Doxygen`s documentation - &plusmn; &infin

Tags: c++, doxygen, infinite

I use Doxygen to generate a documentation :
in *.h file I write the document`s body.For the following line :

```
/// arguments and results are not NaNs or &plusmn; &infin;.
```

non-complete text is generated:

```
 arguments and results are not NaNs or .
```

Can you share your advise/s what and how to solve the problem?

Comment: which format do you generate?

Comment: and which version of Doxygen are you using, HTML with 1.8.3.1 looks OK